# Dedicating RAM to video card

Tags: memory, graphics-card

Not sure if this is the best forum for this. If it is not, can you point me in the general direction of the best one?

I would like to play a video game that needs 1GB of dedicated RAM to the graphics card. When I use the "Can I run it" site, it tells me that there is only 32 MB of dedicated graphics RAM. When I run the game it is unbearably choppy and I am not able to play it.

I have, but cannot post Computer Properties and dxdiag screenshots. The Display screenshot says that I have just about 4GB of RAM for graphics. The computer is running 64bit Win 10 and has 8GB of installed RAM. I have checked all the drivers, they are up to date. I have attempted to go in to the BIOS and change the amount, as recommended by some Google searchage, but there is no option in there that I can find. I've selected every single option I can, just in case it's lurking somewhere I wouldn't expect to find it. Is there anything else that I can do, other than replacing the card, to satisfy the game requirements?

EDIT: (To include Speccy details)

Operating System:   Windows 10 Home 64-bit

CPU:
    Intel Core i3 3240 @ 3.40GHz
    Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology

RAM:
    8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz (11-11-11-28)

Motherboard:
    Dell Inc. 084J0R (CPU 1)

Graphics:
    Generic Non-PnP Monitor (1360x768@60Hz)
    Intel HD Graphics (Dell)
    512MB NVIDIA GeForce 8500 GT (PNY)
    ForceWare version: 341.95
    SLI Disabled

Storage:
    931GB Seagate ST1000DM003-1CH162 (SATA) 40 °C
    14GB USB DISK 3.0 USB Device (USB)

Optical Drives:
    TSSTcorp DVD+-RW SH-216DB

Audio:
    Conexant SmartAudio HD

Comment: What type of computer do you have?  Do you know the type of motherboard, CPU or graphics card you have?  Are your graphics card drivers up to date?

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron 660. Processor is a Intel Core i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz. GC is an NVIDiA Geforce 8500 GT. I  know it's a little bit older, but I'd like to know if there is a way to make it work. As I mentioned, all the drivers are up to date.

Comment: Is your monitor hooked into the VGA/DVI port on your motherboard, or on the card itself?

Comment: Into the card. It displays nothing if plugged in to the "old" port.

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: There are 2 that are requiring, one of which I can't play due to a sub par (for the game) processor as well. Dying Light and Ark: Evolution.

Comment: Try disabling the onboard video memory in your BIOS's settings.  The 32M of RAM is sounding like the system is attempting to use the onboard graphics card instead of the external one.  There should also be an option that states which graphics card it should attempt to boot with first, change it to the addon.

Comment: There is nothing in the BIOS about graphics at all. I've been all over it, into every single option of every menu. Google said I could just change the dedicated RAM in there, so I went looking.

Comment: Can you run [speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) and edit the output into your question?

Comment: What kind of motherboard do you have?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Some background first:

## Normal dedicated graphics card.

This used to be the only way. A card is plugged into the computer. That card has the GPU, its own graphics memory and its own graphics output connector.

In some cases this 'plug in card' is actually build into the motherboard. E.g. on some servers, or on laptops.

## On-board graphics

Not to be confuseed witht the 'on-board plugin card'.

More recently a GPU was added to some chipsets and lately to the CPU-die. This still needs graphics memory to work with. Many of these implementation do not have their own graphics memory though. Instead they 'borrow' from the main memory.

This is cheaper to make, but the speed is lower (and ofc, what is in use for graphics cannot be used for other tasks). Usually you can select how much memory is set aside for this task. Or even the max. allowed for this task and allow the OS to only claim it when needed.

> There is nothing in the BIOS about graphics at all. I've been all over it,
>   into every single option of every menu. Google said I could just change 
>   the dedicated RAM in there, so I went looking.

The google article you found is probably about this. Guessing though since I do not know which one you read.

## Optimus funky stuff.

To make things even more confusing, there are laptops out with both on CPU-die graphics and a decidated GPU. Using the on-die one results in lower performance but also less power used.

When more graphics power is needed the dedicated chip is accessed and its output is passed the on slow setup.

None of this is an actual answer, but I did not prefer to leave a strong of comments either. Hopefully you can add the model of your computer (e.g. if it is a laptop or not. If it is a desktop if the Gf8500 is a physical add-in card etc.

Edits:

1) Motherboard: Dell Inc. 084J0R  -> Dell desktop motherboard. Making a physical Gforece 8500 card likely. And that card is not something which you configure from the motherboard BIOS.

2) The Gforce8500GT is sold as an (old) dedicated card

3) The motherboard has its own VGA out. Make sure that you are not using that. Or if you have multiple monitors connected (both onboard to to the card) that you are trying to game on the monitor connected to the card.

Comment: The computer, as mentioned in a previous comment, is an Inspiron 660. The GC is a physical add on. As previously mentioned, the monitor is coming out of the CG port.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to disable the Intel HD Graphics in BIOS and try again. I've seen the similar situation which is caused by that the game uses the Intel HD graphics first.
If it doesn't work, you may need to consult with the technical support of the manufacturer of this game.

Hope this helps.